# Unable to set top margin NSLayout Constraint programatically in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, constraints

I am trying to set the top margin constraint but it does not work.I have custom cell in which i have two labels.I want to give top spacing dynamic at run time between labels so I have set a constraint of top margin & i have also made outlet of it & using below code to update the top margin.

```
 self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
            self.customCell.nslc_first_comment_margin.constant=-21;
            [self.customCell.first_comment layoutIfNeeded];
```

Please tell how to solve this problem?

**EDIT:**
This code works if write the code inside the **cellForRowAtIndexPath** but this does not work under **heightForRowAtIndexPath**?Can anyone please tell the exact reason for this behaviour.

Comment: Did you try to call layoutIfNeeded on self.customCell.contentView?

Comment: It doesn't change or you are getting wrong position?

Comment: It does not change the postioin

Comment: Yes but not working @MichalMoskala

Comment: Why are calling this line self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO; and then self.customCell.nslc_first_comment_margin.constant=-21;

Comment: i am setting the top spcae as -21 so i am calling this line

Comment: you don't need to call self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

Comment: if reference of nslc_first_comment_margin is correct, it should work

Comment: i have checked everything but nothing seems to be working for me.Please tell me what could be the issue here. I am doing this all in a custom table cell.So is that the issue?

Comment: could you share more code what is self.customCell and how you are init it?

Comment: the cell at heightForRowAtIndexPath is not the cell that appear in tableView

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93520/discussion-between-deepak-kumar-and-ermal-kaleci).